# C# get line number with extracted comment block

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to extract the line number with the comment line from the source code with the codes below

```
foreach (Match match in re.Matches(FileText))
{
    StackFrame CallStack = new StackFrame(0, true);
    sb.Append(match.ToString() + CallStack.GetFileLineNumber() + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

How do I capture each comment with line number e.g. /* Test Comment */ Line: 50

Answer (score 0):

There is no "docs" in the assembly. The docs are generated in form of an XML file and should be distributed along with the assembly. From the call stack, you can get the names of the classes and methods. If you know where the XML files are sitting, then you can for example refer to http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=49 they have the reading of docs per a method mostly done.

However, this is NOT the way the .Net does such things. For having extra compile-time annotations that will survive the compilation and that will be present during the runtime, the .Net allows you to introduce [CustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that can be applied over methods, classes, fields, properties, enums, (....). See that link, look at the example of "Author" attribute and consider changing the magic comment into an attribute. This is the normal way of doing it in whole .Net, not only C#.

Once you read the MethodInfo from the callstack, you can invoke `GetCustomAttributes` on it, and read the data that you have written in them, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx

Comment: Actually i manage to extract the comments block from the sourcecode file but what i want is also to extract the line number from the comment block. Present the output appears like;
Comment 2
Comment 3

But i wanted it to show Comment 1 Line 50
   Comment 2 Line 70
   Comment 3 Line 77

Comment: IIRC, the line numbers of comments blocks are not preserved during compilation phase. You'd have to write a pre- or post- processor to the buiild sequence, to analyze the .cs files and store the data for later use- just like the XML docs gen does - but all by yourself. The only line numbers that are preserved are stored in debug information, but they describe the runnable code, not the attributes, comments or other non-runnables. You may try to play with [#line](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3A_9.5.7_Line_directives) but I do not think it will lead anywhere.